# Exporting P12 certificate concerns

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ssl, certificate

I am still very new to App Development and I have hired a programmer to help me upload an app he has created for me into the iOS app store.

My programmer wants me to export my p12 certificate from my Apple mac to his computer as he told me he needs this to give him the authorization to upload my app build to the app store.

My concern is, if I did this, would it make the private keys/certificates invalid on my mac, whereby I am unable to upload any more apps in the future using this mac?

Thank you

Bruce

Comment: NO. Exporting any certificate/p12 or keys wont affect your mac system as long as you change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting the key won't compromise your Mac, but will allow the developer to act as you in the Apple Store / post the application as if it were you.  Indefinitely.

I wouldn't do this personally and would instead delegate the programmer as a member of your iOS development team in the Developer Center.  You should be able to delegate him / her access to post applications to the App Store as a member of the team; the difference being that (s)he will be doing so under their own identity, and you can at anytime thereafter revoke their access [without having to revoke your own key].

Comment: Thanks heaps for that response. How do you revoke their access if that is the case. Would I have to login to my 'member center' to do this and access one of the options in there?

Comment: See Apple's documentation for the best explanation of the process and implications here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW26

In short, you'll go into the Developer Center, choose Certificates, select the compromised one, and then Revoke.  Do read up on what all that will affect, though, before taking action.

Answer (score 0):

By exporting a p12 from your keychain does not harm your applications in your mac or your certificate. If you trust your developer you can export the p12 for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

No. Exporting any p12/certificate will create a copy of the same. It is ok if exported p12 is used in another machine/system. So you can share/export your p12 file to your developer.